# dd: conv option disabled

Tags: android, imaging, dd

For taking a bit-by-bit image of my Android phone, I am using the dd command but it returns dd: conv option disabled. Kindly let me know how to fix this problem. 
I am writing the command syntax as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p22 of=/sdcard/test.img bs=1024       conv=noerror,notrunc,sync
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many Android phones, the stock binary `dd`  which is at `/system/bin` is not a full version binary supporting conv option. In case you want to use `dd` with conv option, then you have to go for busybox. Install busybox preferably at `/system/xbin`, then delete the stock binary. If you don't want to delete the stock dd, then in your commands or script, `dd` should be prefixed with `busybox`, like `busybox dd` as below.

```
busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p22 of=/sdcard/test.img bs=1024  conv=noerror,notrunc,sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely to be a dd-utility issue.  The GNU dd does not contain that message ('conv option disabled'), but there are small-memory dd versions for Android that have disabled all conv-processing and replaced them with that exact message.

I suggest: find a different Android binary tool distribution, one that doesn't mess with the tools you rely on for your work.  Or get the sources and recompile it as you prefer it.

However, you will run up against the validation problem: don't use forensic tools unless you have verified that they work as you expect them to.